# how to get latitude and longitude of user by hidden form input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to get latitude and longitude of user when he fill form on my website .. when i use this code from w3school   my website not show any results because may be server prevent that ... can you help me to get another method please ??

```html
<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine on jsbin.

Please check the browser support at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)

w3schools also mentions -

> As of Chrome 50, the Geolocation API will only work on secure contexts such as HTTPS.